# How to convert a column with frozen set data into normal list in panndas

Tags: python, dataframe

I am trying to convert a pandas column whose value are in frozenset into normal set.

Column data looks as below. (This is my second column of pandas dataframe. I have integer data on Column 1 and Column 3

```
 frozenset({'apple', 'orange'})
 frozenset({'bananas', 'orange'})
 frozenset({'orange'})
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `df['new_column'] = df['Column 2'].apply(set)` (I assume your dataframe is called 'df' and your column is called 'Column 2')